# How to build a segment tree using python?

Tags: python, data-structures

How to build a segment tree using python......I tried the following code:#

```
def built(arr,start,end,tree,tn):
    if end==start:
        tree[tn]=arr[start]
        return
    mid=(start+end)/2
    built(arr,start,mid,tree,2*tn)
    built(arr,mid+1,end,tree,2*tn+1)
    tree[tn]=tree[2*tn]+tree[2*tn+1]


arr=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
tree=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
built(arr,0,5,tree,1)
for i in tree:
    print (i)
```

what's wrong with the code......giving run time error(list assignment index out of range)

Comment: would you be able to describe better the goal you are trying to achieve? what exactly is a segment tree? what would be the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work

```
def built(arr,start,end,tree,tn):
    if end==start:
        tree[tn]=arr[start]
        return
    mid=(start+end)/2
    built(arr,start,mid,tree,2*tn)
    built(arr,mid+1,end,tree,2*tn+1)
    tree[tn]=tree[2*tn]+tree[2*tn+1]


arr=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
tree=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
built(arr,0,5,tree,1)
for i in tree:
    print (i)
```

Size of your `tree` array should 4 times the size of your `arr`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I also spend some time trying to figure out this:

The segment tree is like this:

```
                  21
            /           \
           6             15      
        /   \       /      \
       3     3     9        6
     / \          / \
    1   2        4   5
```

However, even it seems it only has 11 nodes, but the missing part is 0s, real tree is like this:

```
                  21
            /           \
           6             15      
        /   \       /      \
       3     3     9        6
     / \    / \   / \      / \
    1   2  0   0 4   5    0   0
```

We need 0s because missing 0s can lead to confusion, for example, if missing 0s we cannot tell 4 and 5 is 9's children.

Because segment tree is full binary and balanced (we always divide it into halves). Here we must have tree length >= 16 considering tree start from index 1.

We can allocate tree = [0 for _ in range(16)] and get the right answer: [0, 21, 6, 15, 3, 3, 9, 6, 1, 2, 0, 0, 4, 5, 0, 0].

Here's how we get 4n: if array length is not 2^i, then the tree height should be at least ⎣logn⎦ + 1, so the total tree nodes would be 2*2^(logn+1) = 2^(logn + 2) = 4 * 2^logn = 4 * n

So we normally allocate 4n size tree.

You can also draw the stack of running this code, after running some rounds, the tree[12] would be 4, so that's why the code get error 'index out of range'.

Answer (score 0):

No point going below height of the tree, in that case you can check for start > end and return in case true.

```
def built(arr,start,end,tree,tn):
    if end==start:
        tree[tn]=arr[start]
        return
    elif start > end:
        return
    mid=(start+end)/2
    built(arr,start,mid,tree,2*tn)
    built(arr,mid+1,end,tree,2*tn+1)
    tree[tn]=tree[2*tn]+tree[2*tn+1]


arr=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
tree=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
built(arr,0,5,tree,1)
for i in tree:
    print (i)
```

You can initialise array to build tree as **2 * (2 ** h) - 1**